# Problems with replacement in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace

I cant replace special caracters from portugues like é to UTF-8 code from a a column, example:

bofore      [https://www.linkedin.com/in/andré-pieroni-mesa..](https://www.linkedin.com/in/andr%C3%A9-pieroni-mesa..).
after       https://www.linkedin.com/in/andr%c3%a9-pieroni-mesa...

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd 

import json

dfgetprospect=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\PICHAU\Desktop\Cargo Sapiens\Inteligencia Comercial\Upload empresas\Get Prospect.xlsx')

df= pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\PICHAU\Desktop\Curso Python\Encoding links.csv', delimiter=';')

df=df[['Character','UTF-8']]

df.set_index(keys=['Character'], inplace=True)

​

lista = df.to_dict()

lista=lista['UTF-8']

lista

#lista = json.dumps(lista)

#lista=str(lista).replace("{","").replace("}","")

dfgetprospect['Linkedin Url'].str.replace({lista})

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-fd99a3f16c6e> in <module>
----> 1 dfgetprospect['Linkedin Url'].str.replace({lista})

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

**Example from list:**
{'space': '%20',
'!': '%21',
'"': '%22',
'#': '%23',
'$': '%24',
'%': '%25',
'&': '%26',
"'": '%27',
'(': '%28',
')': '%29',
'*': '%2a',
**example from df:**
û   %c3%bb
ü   %c3%bc
ý   %c3%bd
þ   %c3%be
ÿ   %c3%bf

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`urllib.parse.quote`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/urllib.parse.html) function from the [urllib](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/urllib.html) module

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'urls': ['http://example.org/andré-pieroni-mesa',
                            'http://example.org/!"#$%&\'()*ûüýþÿ']})

import urllib
df['urls_quoted'] = df['urls'].apply(urllib.parse.quote)
```

input:

```
                                    urls
0  http://example.org/andré-pieroni-mesa
1     http://example.org/!"#$%&'()*ûüýþÿ
```

output:

```
                                    urls                                                                        urls_quoted
0  http://example.org/andré-pieroni-mesa                                       http%3A//example.org/andr%C3%A9-pieroni-mesa
1     http://example.org/!"#$%&'()*ûüýþÿ  http%3A//example.org/%21%22%23%24%25%26%27%28%29%2A%C3%BB%C3%BC%C3%BD%C3%BE%C3%BF
```